# drawing specific instances in gl.drawArraysInstanced

Tags: webgl, webgl2

I'm using the instancing technique for rendering lots of rectangles and it's working great to draw everything in one go with **gl.drawArraysInstanced**. However, I'd also like more control of it and to be able to draw a specific or a set of specific rectangle instances.

I've researched quite a while and I didn't find any API call in webgl2 that would help me do it. It seems that the current specification is dated and it doesn't offer an API call that would allow me to take advantage of selectively drawing instances. It looks like that I could use **.glDrawArraysInstancedBaseInstance** but it's not available in webgl2.

The only solution I found was to create an additional buffer for every rectangle, selectively copy data from the instancing buffer to them, and then draw using the additional buffer with **gl.drawArrays** when I need only to render specific rectangles.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: There are some draft extensions for this now: `WEBGL_draw_instanced_base_vertex_base_instance` and
`WEBGL_multi_draw_instanced_base_vertex_base_instance`

Answer (score 1):

I found a better solution, not ideal though.

For specific draws, I bind the instancing vao as usual, then I offset the buffer pointer to the desired instanceID data region with **gl.vertexAttribPointer** and issue **gl.drawArraysInstanced** with only one instance.

Alternatively, When I need to draw all instances, I set the offset back to the beginning of the buffer and issue the drawing operations with all instances.